# service not getting executed when bash script is triggered from php

Tags: php, mysql, apache, bash, unix

I trigger with PHP this code:

```
    $dexec="cd /var/server_status/ && sh server_restart.sh";
    $d=exec($dexec,$a,$b);
```

server_restart.sh:
`service mysql stop`

$b dump is int 127, command not found, not in the path when it was triggered from php? the service command? what could be the steps to have this working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats a path problem. PHP can't find the file.
Add a `chdir("/var/server_status");` to switch to the dir where server_restart.sh is.

Comment: it gets to trigger the file, there's a few other contents like email sendage that get to work, service mysql stop changed to /usr/bin/service mysql stop and still won't work

Comment: Has the user running "PHP" the permission to run the "service" command? Give "sudo -u" a shot..